# How to attach a different DataTemplate to the Same Hierarchical Template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to attach different DataTemplates so that the children render differently to the same HierarchicalDataTemplate, which as I understand controls the View of the header

I am trying to do it without success::

```
<Window.Resources>
       <DataTemplate 
            x:Key="ChildTemplate1">
                <Label Content="Blah">

        </DataTemplate>
       <DataTemplate 
            x:Key="ChildTemplate2">
                <Label Content="Blah2">

        </DataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
            x:Key="RootTemplate"
            ItemTemplate={StaticResource ChildTemplate2}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <Label Content="Header">
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

    <TreeView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RootTemplate}">
        <TreeViewItem ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate1}"/>
    </TreeView>
```

So again, what I am trying to do is override the DataTemplate set in HierarchicalDataTemplate(ChildTemplate2) with ChildTemplate1

Comment: where do you wanted to attach those different templates?

Comment: I have two treeviews that would use the same template for the Header/Root Items and different Templates for the the children. In the example I just listed the first Treeview

Comment: are you looking for [HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx)? perhaps you may use [HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.itemtemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) to switch the template based on conditions.